# UPDATE statement with multidimensional $_GET

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an UPDATE statement with the values form a multidimensional $_GET

```
  Array
(
    [social_link] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.facebook.com
            [1] => https://www.twitter.com
        )

    [social_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [social_network] => Array
        (
            [0] => facebook
            [1] => twitter
        )

)
```

My DB table is `'Social'` with `'_ID , social_network, social_link'` row names

SQL that i tried

```
foreach ($_GET as $index ) {
$sql = "UPDATE Social SET social_link= '{$index['social_link']}' WHERE _ID= '{$index['social_id']}' AND social_network= '{$index ['social_network']}' ";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
}
```

But its not working.

Comment: Will the indexes always match?  For example, social_link[0] relates to social_id[0] and social_network[0]?  Your current SQL doesn't work because you are iterating through the $_GET array, so the first element in that array is the social_link array which doesn't have a key 'social_link' in it.

Comment: Stupid question.... but when you set $sql are you actually executing the query?

Comment: That'll interpolate everything as `Array`. Use a loop, and utilize `->execute` parameters instead.

Comment: $conn is an instance of mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly rough method of accomplishing what you're trying to do, I believe. It will also ensure that all three variables are available before trying to do an update.

```php
<?php

// Loop through based on number of social IDs present
for( $i = 0, $icount = count( $_GET['social_id'] ); $i < $icount; $i++ )
{
    // Get values of social_id, social_link, and social_network
    // If they're not set, set them to false
    $social_id      = ( isset( $_GET['social_id'][$i] )      ? $_GET['social_id'][$i]      : false );
    $social_link    = ( isset( $_GET['social_link'][$i] )    ? $_GET['social_link'][$i]    : false );
    $social_network = ( isset( $_GET['social_network'][$i] ) ? $_GET['social_network'][$i] : false );

    // If all values are present for this entry, update the row
    if( $social_id !== false && $social_link !== false && $social_network !== false )
    {
        $sql  = "UPDATE Social 
                 SET    social_link = '{$social_link}'
                 WHERE  _ID = '{$social_id}' AND social_network = '{social_network}'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

You should alter it as you see fit, but I would also recommend that you utilise parameter binding for your queries.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you'd build your query string like

```
social[0][link]=https://www.facebook.com&social[0][id]=1&social[0][network]=facebook&
social[1][link]=https://www.twitter.com&social[1][id]=2&social[1][network]=twitter
```

([http_build_query()](http://docs.php.net/http_build_query) can help you building that string.)

This would result in _GET "looking like"

```
$_GET === [ 'social'=>
    [
        [ 'link'=>'https://www.facebook.com', 'id'=>'1', 'network'=>'facebook' ],
        [ 'link'=>'https://www.twitter.com', 'id'=>'2', 'network'=>'twitter' ]
    ]
];
```

and the script for iterating the data like

```
<?php
$sql = "
    UPDATE
        Social
    SET
        social_link=?
    WHERE
        _ID=?
        AND social_network=?
";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)
    or trigger_error( 'prepare failed: '.join(',', $conn->error_list), E_USER_ERROR );
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $link, $id, $network)
    or trigger_error( 'bind failed: '.join(',', $stmt->error_list), E_USER_ERROR );

// <-- test isset($_GET['social']) && is_array($_GET['social']) before here -->
foreach ($_GET['social'] as $row ) {
    // <-- test existence of $row[link,id,network] here -->
    $link = $row['link'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $network = $row['network'];
    $stmt->execute()
        or trigger_error( 'execute failed: '.join(',', $stmt->error_list), E_USER_ERROR );
}
```

Btw: You perform an UPDATE operation and it seems as if this is also the primary action of the script as seen from the client's perspective. Therefore you should use POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

For the array that you posted, you are not iterating right over the multidimensional array.

Making some assumptions... the code might be

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($_GET[social_link]); $i++) {
    $sql = "UPDATE Social SET social_link= '{$_GET['social_link'][$i]}' WHERE _ID= '{$_GET['social_id'][$i]}' AND social_network= '{$_GET ['social_network'][$i]}' ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Also, always remember: everytime you use `$_GET` directly in SQL a cute kitty is killed by a [SQL injection attack](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom).